# How to detect click event on dropdown, but not on the options menu in Javascript (or differentiate between the two)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I have a simple dropdown in my code that I attach a click hander to, like so (code is technically typescript)

```
this.highElement.click(() => {
    console.log(event);
});
```

This event is triggered both when I click the select box AND when I click one of the options (Here's a Js fiddle that demonstrates what I mean https://jsfiddle.net/Kolichikov/zmdL6q2d/). What I would like ideally is for the event to only fire when I click the select box itself, not the resulting list of items.

I tried setting a delegated event for the option `this.highElement.on("click", "option", () => { console.log("option!"); });`, but that didn't work.

I have noticed that the `MouseEvent` properties are different (the mouse coordinates aren't populated when an item is clicked), but this seems like a browser implementation that could change (maybe?).

Is there a way to properly differentiate between the two events?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll give you 2 options, you pick the one it's best for you:

First you can differentiate between the 2 events like this:

```
$("#selectItem").click(function(event){
    if (event.target.id == 'selectItem') 
        console.log(event)
});
```

the event has a different target when it returns from clicking in select and from choosing an option.

But I think it would be much clearer if you used the change event

```
$("#selectItem").change(function(event){
     console.log(event)
});
```

it fires only when you select an item. Depending on what you need this could be better.

**EDIT**

Checkingwhat @libzz said, I notice that the first part of the above response is wrong. I didn't edit it because the OP accepted the answer as is and I'd be changing the code that lead to his decision.

But as @libzz said, the event when fired has always the same id.

What I also noticed now is that the click event only fires when an option is clicked, not when the select box is clicked. That levels the onclick with the onchange event. They basically do the same thing in this case.

So in order to make code clearer, the best would be using only onchange event for selects.

Comment: It seems both `select` and `option` elements refer to the same id. So, the first one with the click event doesn't work.